# MS SQL Server много (на 290 Гб) файлов .dmp

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server насоздавал кучу файлов .dmp аж на 287 гигов. Как я понял такие файлы нужны для различных бекапов\восстановлений или что-то типо того. Обнаруил это с помощью WizTree. Нужна помощь в следующих вопросах:

- Могу ли я их удалить?
- Как мне их удалить?(винда ругается говорит нет доступа)
- И как мне отключить это, чтобы оно само так много файлов не создавала?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вряд ли уж в папке `log` будут данные для восстановления, правда?

Comment: А ну торможу. Т е я могу это с лёгкой душой чистить?

Comment: Я бы ещё советовал  папку ```system32``` удалить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расширение `dmp` используется в windows для хранения дампов процессов. Как правило это сохранение дампов при падении приложения, чтобы можно было отладить ошибки. Удалить их можно, но я бы заинтересовался тем, почему SQL Server так часто падает.

Comment: Может быть потому что я как бы не работаю с ним особо. Чисто для учёбы на компе стоит (покачто). И как бы я там ничего особо не делаю практически: открыл, скриптик написал для лабки, закрыл. Либо вообще не трогал его, а-ля: комп запустил, позанимался вообще делами не относящимися к SQL, вырубил комп.

Comment: Ну раз это не боевая система, удаляйте дампы и можете не разбираться почему падает.

Comment: Просто эта система стоит на ССД, а для него не есть хорошо постоянно запись файлов. И если это можно както остановить/ограничить переодичность/размер файлов или ещё чтото в этом духе - было бы замечательно

Comment: Способа отключить генерацию дампов при падении не знаю, но можно отключить падающий компонент. В данном случае это polybase. Надо установить сервисам SQL server polybase data movement и SQL server polybase engine тип старта на manual.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Пока что дампы не плодятся.

Answer (score -1):

Это тебе еще судя по всему повезло, потому что когда я просканировал диск и увидел это, я действительно удивился, 1.2 TB это не очень смешно, хотя и забавно..
[image: 1.2 TB]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/742006)